# What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, datetime

Postgres can round (truncate) timestamps using the date_trunc function, like this:

```
date_trunc('hour', val)
date_trunc('minute', val)
```

I'm looking for a way to truncate a timestamp to the nearest 5-minute boundary so, for example, 14:26:57 becomes 14:25:00.  The straightforward way to do it is like this:

```
date_trunc('hour', val) + date_part('minute', val)::int / 5 * interval '5 min'
```

Since this is a performance-critical part of the query, I'm wondering whether this is the fastest solution, or whether there's some shortcut (compatible with Postgres 8.1+) that I've overlooked.

Comment: Why not turn that into a function and then index on it and see how fast it is then?  Or just index right on that exact same logic without wrapping it in an index.  either way you'll get an idea how fast it can be.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8963684/287948

Comment: A note, this method does not seem to round up to the "nearest" boundary, but rounds _down_ to the next _lowest_ boundary. i.e. '2017-04-01 00:04:00' appears to round to '2017-04-01 00:00:00', not _up_ to the _nearest_ boundary, which would be '2017-04-01 00:05:00'

Comment: This operation soon will be much simpler with [date_bin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907341/5070879) function

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there is any quicker method.

And I don't think you should be worried about the performance of the expression.

Everything else that is involved in executing your (SELECT, UPDATE, ...) statement is most probably a lot more expensive (e.g. the I/O to retrieve rows) than that date/time calculation.

Answer (score 33):

I was wondering the same thing. I found two alternative ways of doing this, but the one you suggested was faster.

I informally benchmarked against one of our larger tables. I limited the query to the first 4 million rows. I alternated between the two queries in order to avoid giving one a unfair advantage due to db caching.

---

### Going through epoch/unix time

```
SELECT to_timestamp(
    floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM ht.time) / EXTRACT(epoch FROM interval '5 min'))
    * EXTRACT(epoch FROM interval '5 min')
) FROM huge_table AS ht LIMIT 4000000
```

(Note this produces `timestamptz`even if you used a time zone unaware datatype)

**Results**

- **Run 1**: 39.368 seconds
- **Run 3**: 39.526 seconds
- **Run 5**: 39.883 seconds

---

### Using date_trunc and date_part

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('hour', ht.time) 
    + date_part('minute', ht.time)::int / 5 * interval '5 min'
FROM huge_table AS ht LIMIT 4000000
```

**Results**

- **Run 2**: 34.189 seconds
- **Run 4**: 37.028 seconds
- **Run 6**: 32.397 seconds

---

**System**

- DB version: PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
- Cores: Intel® Xeon®, E5-1650v2, Hexa-Core
- RAM: 64 GB, DDR3 ECC RAM

### Conclusion

Your version seems to be faster. But not fast enough for my specific use case. The advantage of not having to specify the hour makes the epoch version more versatile and produces simpler parameterization in client side code. It handles `2 hour` intervals just as well as `5 minute` intervals without having to bump the `date_trunc` time unit argument up. On a end note, I wish this time unit argument was changed to a time interval argument instead.

Comment: The first version should use `floor` instead of casting to int - since the casting may round up leading to wrong results (`select 0.9::int -- =1`)

Comment: @Pyrocks Thank you so much. I've worked with postgres for years, and now is the first time I learned that casting to int "rounds" instead of "truncates" decimals. All programming languages I've come across truncates, so I just assumed it applied to postgres (and other databases?). I've updated the answer, but I don't have time to rerun the query. I hope it doesn't affect it too much.

Comment: I would add function trunc_minute for convenience based on this answer: create or replace function trunc_minute(ts timestamptz, n int) returns timestamptz language sql as $sql$ select date_trunc('hour',ts)+trunc(date_part('minute',ts)/n)*n*interval '1 minute'$sql$;

Answer (score 9):

Since **Postgres 14**, [**`date_bin()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) is **simplest and fastest**:

```
date_bin('5 min', val, '2000-1-1')
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN)

> The function `date_bin` “bins” the input timestamp into the specified
> interval (the stride) aligned with a specified origin.
>
> `date_bin`(`stride`, `source`, `origin`)
>
> ***`source`*** is a value expression of type `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`. (Values of type `date` are cast automatically to
> `timestamp`.) ***`stride`*** is a value expression of type interval.
> The return value is likewise of type `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`, and it marks the beginning of the bin into which the
> ***`source`*** is placed.

Provide an "origin" of matching data type to avoid unexpected results from the cast ignoring time zones or assuming the wrong one.

My example *looks* like a `date` literal but serves as valid `timestamp` literal, too. If the time component is missing '00:00' is assumed.

Related:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Answer (score 3):

Full query for those wondering (based on @DNS question):

Assuming you have orders and you want to count them by slices of 5min and shop_id:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', created_at) + date_part('minute', created_at)::int / 5 * interval '5 min' AS minute
      , shop_id, count(id) as orders_count
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1, shop_id
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: Ever used the Django ORM? Any idea on how to do this without a custom SQL query.