# Django Trunc data to 15 minutes

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I am currently using the [`Truc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) function of Django to aggregate some data within the day and hour.

I would like to do the same but over 15 minutes, instead of an hour or just a minute but I can't figure it out.

Here is an example of my current query:

```
data_trunc = data_qs.annotate(
   start_day=Trunc('date_created', 'minute', output_field=DateTimeField()))
   .values('start_day', 'content', 'device')
```

The problem lies with the `'minutes'` argument that can be passed to `Trunc`. As far as I get it, there is no choice inbetween `'hour'` and `'minutes'`.

*How can I group my data over 15 minutes and have a larger time span for the data grouping ?*

I know that I could do this by hand afterward but I'd really like to have the database do this for me since there is a large dataset to compute and this way is the most efficient one I have yet.
If this is the only way though I am opened to suggestions to the most efficient ways to get around this.

Thanks for your help

---

*Edit*
I should have specified I did not wish to use raw SQL to do this and stick with Django ORM or native Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299342/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-truncate-timestamps-to-5-minutes-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Since I do not want to go along the path of using Postgres functions and stick with the ORM, I ended up manually trunc-ing the data iterating all items.

```
def trunc_minutes(raw_data, groupping=15):

truncated_arranged = []
current_slice = []
end_time = raw_data[0]['start_day'] + timedelta(minutes=groupping)

for d in raw_data:
    if d['start_day'] <= end_time:
        current_slice.append(d)
    else:
        truncated_arranged.append(current_slice)
        current_slice = [d]
        end_time = d['start_day'] + timedelta(minutes=groupping)

return truncated_arranged
```

This might not be the fastest way but it works and does not require raw SQL.

---

**Edit**: Add `d` in the `else` part of the code so that the value that get in the new slice isn't forgotten

Comment: I think there is small problem with the loop. When ever the loop falls in the else condition it will not store the current value in d anywhere and move over to the next loop.

Comment: Long time I didn't use that code, maybe the 2nd line of the 'else' part should be `current_slice = [d]` so that this value is not forgotten? Have you tried ?

Comment: Seems like I had added an append in my code at the time, I'll just edit