# How can optimize this Postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table which has time series data. I want to aggregate values over configurable periods and durations e.g. aggregate tag-n over 30-minute intervals for one day. The output should look like -

| Period | Max | Min | Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | xx | xx | xx |
| 00:30 | xx | xx | xx |
| 01:00 | xx | xx | xx |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 23:30 | xx | xx | xx |

To do this, I created a function to generate the custom intervals and then used this function in the query -

```
create or replace function interval_generator(start_ts timestamp, end_ts timestamp, round_interval INTERVAL) 
returns TABLE(row_seq bigint,start_time timestamp,end_time timestamp) as $$ 
BEGIN 
return query 
SELECT row_number() over () row_seq,(n) start_time,(n + round_interval) end_time 
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('minute', start_ts), end_ts, round_interval) n;
END $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

```
with intervals as (select * from interval_generator('2022-08-25 00:00:00','2022-08-26 23:59:59','30 Minute'::INTERVAL)) 
select intervals.row_seq,intervals.start_time,max("Value"),min("Value"),avg("Value") 
from public.<TableName> inner JOIN intervals on "TimeStamp" >= intervals.start_time and "TimeStamp" < intervals.end_time 
WHERE "Tag"=xxxxxxxxxx
GROUP BY intervals.row_seq,intervals.start_time 
ORDER BY intervals.row_seq asc
```

I needed an additional column (first one) for the rest of the application logic.
Is this the best way to get the desired output in a single query? Or is splitting the query into multiple ones, one query for each interval, better?

I am in no way an expert in SQL or Postgresql, I put together the above queries using my Google skills. It works, but I am not sure if this is optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always found that joining using any inequality (>, <, between) to be horribly inefficient.  Under the covers it appears to do a cartesian join and then filter out values.  I can't swear to that, but benchmarks have shown that if there is any way around it you should.

In this case, I think should convert each timestamp to the interval desired using `date_trunc`.  Unfortunately there is no native `date_trunc` for 30 minutes, but there is a way around that this:

[What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7299342/1001884)

Using the concept in the link above, I think you can optimize your query significantly by avoiding the generate series / cartesian:

```
select
  date_trunc('hour', "TimeStamp") +
    date_part('minute', "TimeStamp")::int / 30 * interval '30 min' as start_time,
  max("Value"),min("Value"),avg("Value") 
from public.<TableName> 
WHERE "Tag"=xxxxxxxxxx
GROUP BY start_time
ORDER BY start_time
```

If you need the row_seq, I would recommend using row_number().