# How to round up when using generate_series()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, generate-series

I've have a Postgres database and I'm using Grafana to visualise some data.

For instance, my Grafana panel has the following variables where the values are dynamic:

- $__timeFrom() = '2023-10-21T00:00:00Z'
- $__timeTo() = '2023-10-21T00:25:00Z'
- $__interval = '15m'

These variables are used to generate a time series table, where the time is generated like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series('2023-10-21T00:00:00Z'::timestamp, '2023-10-21T00:25:00Z'::timestamp, '15m')
ORDER BY 1;
```

The above query gives me the following slots:

- 2023-10-21 00:00:00.000000
- 2023-10-21 00:15:00.000000

But I would like it to round up and generate a slot for the remaining time, by having a third slot with either the end date or the next value in the interval:

- 2023-10-21 00:00:00.000000
- 2023-10-21 00:15:00.000000
- 2023-10-21 00:25:00.000000 / 2023-10-21 00:30:00.000000

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

that depends what result you need

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series('2023-10-21T00:00:00Z'::timestamp, '2023-10-21T00:25:00Z'::timestamp + interval '15 minute', '15m')
ORDER BY 1;
```

| generate_series |
| --- |
| 2023-10-21 00:00:00 |
| 2023-10-21 00:15:00 |
| 2023-10-21 00:30:00 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series('2023-10-21T00:00:00Z'::timestamp, '2023-10-21T00:25:00Z'::timestamp, '15m')
  UNION SELECT '2023-10-21T00:25:00Z'::timestamp
ORDER BY 1;
```

| generate_series |
| --- |
| 2023-10-21 00:00:00 |
| 2023-10-21 00:15:00 |
| 2023-10-21 00:25:00 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ef9IYVJU)

Answer (score 0):

> ... by having a third slot with either the end date or **the next value in the interval**:

To get the latter (bold emphasis), get the "floor" for the next full interval with [`date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) and add one stride:

```
SELECT generate_series(a, date_bin(intv, z, a) + intv, intv);
```

See:

- [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299342/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-truncate-timestamps-to-5-minutes-in-postgres/75160734#75160734)

That goes one step too far when the end falls on the full interval exactly. To also fix that corner case:

```
SELECT generate_series(a, CASE WHEN date_bin(intv, z, a) = z THEN z ELSE date_bin(intv, z, a) + intv END, intv)
```

Demo with input values:

```sql
SELECT generate_series(a, CASE WHEN date_bin(intv, z, a) = z THEN z ELSE date_bin(intv, z, a) + intv END, intv)
FROM  (
   VALUES (timestamp '2023-10-21 00:00'
         , timestamp '2023-10-21 00:25'
         , interval '15 min')
   ) input(a, z, intv);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j3TW8E_C)

A bit more verbose than [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk)'s smart solution with `UNION`, but computing the ceiling once should be faster than running a `UNION` over a possibly large set.
Also, this ends on the next interval, while nbk ends on the given value. You may prefer one or the other.