# postgresql date_trunc to arbitrary precision?

Tags: postgresql

postgresql has `date_trunc` that can truncate the time stamp value to a specific unit, like *hour* or *minute*. I want to know if there's any build-in function that would allow me to truncate to **10 minutes**?

I know one trick is to convert the time stamp to epoch, do some math, then convert back. But I don't like it.

Comment: PostgreSQL 14 will support such operation out-of-the box:https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907341/5070879

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function you want, but as said in [postgresql wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Round_time) you can define function for youself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_time_10m(TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AS $$ 
  SELECT date_trunc('hour', $1) + INTERVAL '10 min' * ROUND(date_part('minute', $1) / 10.0) 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Generally rounding up to $2 minutes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_time_nm(TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, INTEGER) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AS $$ 
  SELECT date_trunc('hour', $1) + ($2 || ' min')::INTERVAL * ROUND(date_part('minute', $1) / $2) 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: @alex-dvortsky Thank you very much. Can you help me come up with a solution that I can use *n* as the round up unit? Say `interval 'n min'`

Comment: Quick update needed: the prototype of the second function is wrong:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_time_nm(TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, INTEGER) ` would be more accurate (edited the name, added missing second parameter)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed signature of the function

Comment: the second function seems to not actually work: `jasen=# select  round_time_nm(now(),10);
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+-----------------------
round_time_nm | 2019-03-17 23:02:00+00
`

Comment: @Jasen you are right. Fixed the function. Thank you for pointing

Answer (score 3):

here's an improved version of date_trunc

```
create cast (bigint as timestamptz) WITHOUT FUNCTION;
create cast (timestamptz as bigint) WITHOUT FUNCTION;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_trunc_by_interval( interval, timestamptz )
    RETURNS timestamptz 
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    AS $$ 
    select
        case when $2::bigint >= 0::bigint then
            $2::bigint - $2::bigint % (extract (epoch from $1)*1000000 ) ::bigint 
        else
            $2::bigint - $2::bigint % (extract (epoch from $1)*1000000 ) ::bigint 
            - (extract (epoch from $1)*1000000 ) ::bigint
        end ::timestamptz
$$;
```

this allows rounding to any fixed-length interval eg: '864 seconds' (divinding days into 100 parts)  or '14 days'  dividing the calendar into fortnights. the basis is '2000-01-01 00:00:00.0 +00' which is the epoch used to compute postgres 
timestamp values.

it works by coercing the timestamptz value and the interval into bigints and doing integer arithmetic on them then coercing them back to timestamps

negative inputs need special handling (the case statement) as % causes rounding towards zero.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres 14 [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN).
Example use

```sql
SELECT date_bin('15 minutes', TIMESTAMP '2020-02-11 15:44:17', TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01');
```

```
Result: 2020-02-11 15:30:00
```

The **timescaleDb** extension has a [time_bucket](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#time_bucket) function that supports day, minutes and lower intervals.